# Why is this calculator giving me 'Input string was not in correct format' Error?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, calculator

I'm doing this calculator using System.Windows.Forms and everytime I try to do a Square Root, Cos, Sin or Tan operation and hit the Equals button it stops and tells me 'System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format' and I don't know why.

This is my buttonEquals_Click event:

```
private void buttonEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double num2;
    double answer;

    num2 = double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);

    switch (theOperator)
    {
        case "+":
            answer = resultValue + num2;
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "-":
            answer = resultValue - num2;
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "×":
            answer = resultValue * num2;
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "÷":
            answer = resultValue / num2;
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "sqrt":
            answer = Math.Sqrt(resultValue);
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "exp":
            answer = Math.Pow(resultValue, num2);
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "sin":
            answer = Math.Sin(resultValue);
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "cos":
            answer = Math.Cos(resultValue);
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        case "tan":
            answer = Math.Tan(resultValue); 
            textBoxResult.Text = answer.ToString();
            resultValue = 0;
            break;
        default:
            answer = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

and this is my SqrtButton_Click event and DivisionButton_event (so you can see that with DivisionButton it does work):

```
private void SqrtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resultValue = resultValue + double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);
    theOperator = "sqrt";
    textBoxResult.Clear();
}

private void DivisionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resultValue = resultValue + double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);
    theOperator = "÷";
    textBoxResult.Clear();
}
```

I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT: The exception is trown at: `num2 = double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);`

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you set a breakpoint in `SqrtButtonClick`? Is the value appropriate to pass to `double.Parse`?
 What about in the `case` for `"sqrt"` when you examine `resultValue`? Is the value what would be appropriate to pass to the function `sqrt`?

Comment: Now you have your answer. *Invalid input string*

Comment: It doesn't get to the next line. It stops at `num2 = double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);` but if I place the breakpoint in the `case` for Division it does enter the case.

Comment: @HernánCasillas breakpoints are super easy in visual studio and they are your friend.  Good luck!

Comment: @IanRay thanks, the question has been answered.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks! I'm going to get used to debug all my programs because debugging is something I barely do.

Comment: Please carefully read [MCVE] guidance on posting code and search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+input+string+was+not+in+a+correct+format for error messages before posting future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gonna guess that when you try to test those guys, the `textBoxResult` is empty.  Notice that you're executing the line `num2 = double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);`  If textBoxResult was recently cleared, then you would have an issue here of the form `System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format` (an empty string/null does not get parsed by double.Parse as a 0.00)

Comment: Thanks man, I removed the `textBoxResult.Clear()` from Sqrt, Cos, Sin and Tan and it worked! I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was wondering, who downvoted this answer!

Comment: I did not down vote, but I would guess that a down vote would be due to the fact that this explains *why* the error is occurring, but not *how to prevent it* (i.e. some discussion of `double.TryParse()` and/or validating the `Text` property first).